# How do you subtract two JSON INTs based on JSON date ranges?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a database that contains userName and entry_data (User Input in JSON that includes value and entryDate).

Here is an example of what the table looks like:

```
| userName | value | entryDate |
| ________ | _____ | __________|
| Aaron    | 1234  | 7/25/2022 |
| Aaron    | 6463  | 7/26/2022 |
| Aaron    | 8375  | 7/27/2022 |
| Aaron    | 2734  | 7/28/2022 |
| Aaron    | 4563  | 7/29/2022 |
| Aaron    | 7374  | 7/30/2022 |
| Aaron    | 8923  | 7/31/2022 |
| Aaron    | 6737  | 8/1/2022  |
| Aaron    | 1374  | 8/2/2022  |
| Aaron    | 1834  | 8/3/2022  |
| Aaron    | 3646  | 8/4/2022  |
| Aaron    | 7834  | 8/5/2022  |
| Aaron    | 2473  | 8/6/2022  |
| Aaron    | 4673  | 8/7/2022  |
```

I'm tasked with summing the values (totalValue), summing the values by week (7/25-7/31 = week1Value, 8/1-8/7 = week2Value) and finding the difference week over week (week2Value - week1Value = WoWDifference), so it'd look something like this:

```
| userName | totalValue | week1Value | week2Value | WoWDifference |
| ________ | __________ | __________ | __________ | _____________ |
| Aaron    |   76,071   |   39,666   |   36,405   |    -3,261     |
```

I'm unfamiliar with 'grouping' and subtracting the values within the date ranges. This is how I've grouped things so far:

```
SELECT
    userName,
    cast((entry_data ->> 'value') as Int) as totalValue,
    case
         when (entry_data ->> 'week1Value')::DATE BETWEEN '2022-07-25' AND '2022-07-31' then 'week1'
         when (entry_data ->> 'week2Value')::DATE BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-07' then 'week2'
    end as timeframe,
FROM entry
```

Output:

```
| userName | totalValue | timeframe|
| ________ | __________ | ________ |
| Aaron    |   39,666   |  week1   |
| Aaron    |   36,405   |  week2   |
```

How do I pull the totalValue sum by week to get the difference between the weeks?

Comment: Your input data and query shared does not looks aligned in terms of JSON data-type. It would help to answer if you can include a create table statement in your question as per the source table structure and data-type(s).

Comment: Please start with your version of Postgres, and show a complete setup with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. Is this for two given weeks or for a whole time range with multiple result rows?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    userName,
    sum(entry_data ->> 'value') as totalValue,
    case when (entry_data ->> 'week1Value')::DATE BETWEEN '2022-07-25' AND '2022-07-31' 
             then sum(entry_data ->> 'value') AS week1 /* changed */
    case when (entry_data ->> 'week2Value')::DATE BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-07' 
             then sum(entry_data ->> 'value') AS week2 /* changed */
FROM entry
group by userName /* changed */
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the direction I needed.

The issue I'm running into now is that week1 and week2 are on separate rows instead of being in the same one for each userName. I've added DISTINCT as well with no luck. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The query that you have, with one case block the query will generate two rows. I changed the query to have two case blocks and added group by userName.
You can put this query into a CTE and query from there to get the weekly difference.
if you provide some sample data, then I can provide you the query that can run.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (similar to @Y Bai) assuming dates are continuous.

```
with data as
  (select *, ceil(row_number() over (order by 0)::decimal/7)::integer rn 
  from entry)
select username,sum(to_number(entry_data->>'value','9999999')) total_value,
  sum (case when rn = 1 then
  to_number(entry_data->>'value','9999999')
  else 0
end) week_1_total,
sum (case when rn = 2 then
  to_number(entry_data->>'value','9999999')
  else 0
end) week_2_total
from data
group by username;
```

Or, use below query using `CROSSTAB` -

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT username, total_value,
    week_no, total_weekly
    FROM  (
        with data as (
            select e.username, e.rn week_no,
            (select sum(to_number(entry_data->>$$value$$,$$9999999$$)) 
            from entry) total_value,
            sum(to_number(entry_data->>$$value$$,$$9999999$$)) total_weekly
            from 
            (select *, 
            ceil(row_number() over 
            (partition by username order by 0)::decimal/7)::integer rn 
            from entry) e
            group by
            e.username, total_value, e.rn
            )
        select username,
        week_no,
        total_value,
        total_weekly
        from data
        union all
        select username,
        (select max(week_no) from data) + 
        row_number() over (partition by username order by 0),
        total_value,
        total_weekly - coalesce(lag(total_weekly) over (order by week_no), 0)
        from data ) x 
        ORDER  BY 1' 
        ,$$VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)$$
   ) AS ct 
   ("username" text, 
   "total_value" int,
   "Week_1" int, 
   "Week_2" int, 
   "Week_3" int,
   "Weekdiff_1" int, 
   "Weekdiff_2" int, 
   "Weekdiff_3" int
);
```

Refer to fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=284d34357e849120395f55eabdecb3e5).

The above fiddle also explores case with extrapolated data using both `crosstab` and manual method for pivot'ing.

There still can be cases which above might not handle, such as if there are less then 7 rows or its not a full week, but it provides a generic approach and can be modified to cater to specific use-cases.

The hard-coding in `values clause of crosstab` can also be replaced with a query to generate a number list of double the values as there are number of weeks present for a given user name.